# spark aggregation with sorted rows that returns a row's value before a condition is met

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have some data (invoice data). Assuming `id ~ date` and `id` is what I'm sorting by:

```
fid, id, due, overdue
  0,  1,   5,       0
  0,  3,   5,       5
  0, 13,   5,      10
  0, 14,   5,       0

  1,  5,   5,       0
  1, 26,   5,       5
  1, 27,   5,       10
  1, 38,   5,       0
```

0. remove all rows under some arbitrary date-id `id = 20`
1. group_by `fid` and sort by `id` within the group
2. (major) aggregate a new column `overdue_id` that is the `id` of the row before the first row in the group that has a nonzero value for `overdue`
3. (minor) fill a row for every `fid` even if all rows are filtered out by #0

so the output would be (given default value null)

```
fid, overdue_id
  0,          1
  1,       null
```

because for `fid = 0`, the first id with nonzero `overdue` is `id = 3`, and I'd like to output the id for the row that before that in `id-date` time which is `id = 1`.

I have `group_by('fid').withColumn('overdue_id', ...)`, and want to use functions like `agg`, `min`, `when`, but am not sure after that as I am very new to the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following steps to solve :

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import *

#added  fid=2 for overdue = 0 condition 
fid = [0,1,2]*4
fid.sort()

dateId = [1,3,13,14,5,26,27,28]
dateId.extend(range(90,95))
due = [5]*12
overdue = [0,5,10,0]*2
overdue.extend([0,0,0,0])

data = zip(fid, dateId, due, overdue)

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema =["fid", "dateId", "due", "overdue"])

win = Window.partitionBy(df['fid']).orderBy(df['dateId'])

res = df\
.filter(F.col("dateId")!= 20)\
.withColumn("lag_id", F.lag(F.col("dateId"), 1).over(win))\
.withColumn("overdue_id", F.when(F.col("overdue")!=0, F.col("lag_id")).otherwise(None))\
.groupBy("fid")\
.agg(F.min("overdue_id").alias("min_overdue_id"))

>>> res.show()
+---+--------------+
|fid|min_overdue_id|
+---+--------------+
|  0|             1|
|  1|             5|
|  2|          null|
+---+--------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the lag and window function. Before we begin, why is your example output showing null for fid 1. The first non zero value is for id 26, so the id before that is 5. so shouldn't be 5? Unless you need something else, you can try this.

```
tst=sqlContext.createDataFrame([(0, 1,5,0),(0,20,5,0),(0,30,5,5),(0,13,5,10),(0,14,5,0),(1,5,5,0),(1,26,5,5),(1,27,5,10),(1,38,5,0)],schema=["fid","id","due","overdue"])
# To filter data
tst_f = tst.where('id!=20')
# Define window function
w=Window.partitionBy('fid').orderBy('id')
tst_lag = tst_f.withColumn('overdue_id',F.lag('id').over(w))
# Remove rows with 0 overdue
tst_od = tst_lag.where('overdue!=0')
# Find the row before first non zero overdue
tst_res = tst_od.groupby('fid').agg(F.first('overdue_id').alias('overdue_id'))
tst_res.show()
+---+----------+
|fid|overdue_id|
+---+----------+
|  0|         1|
|  1|         5|
+---+----------+
```

If you are weary about using the first function , or just to be confident about avoiding ghost issues, you can try the below performance expensive option

```
# Create a copy to avoid ambiguous join and select the minimum from non zero overdue rows
tst_min= tst_od.withColumn("dummy",F.lit('dummy')).groupby('fid').agg(F.min('id').alias('id_min'))
# Join this with the dataframe to get results
tst_join = tst_od.join(tst_min,on=tst_od.id==tst_min.id_min,how='right')
tst_join.show()
+---+---+---+-------+----------+---+------+
|fid| id|due|overdue|overdue_id|fid|id_min|
+---+---+---+-------+----------+---+------+
|  1| 26|  5|      5|         5|  1|    26|
|  0| 13|  5|     10|         1|  0|    13|
+---+---+---+-------+----------+---+------+
# This way you can see all the information
```

You can filter the relevant information from this dataframe using filter() or where() method